# How to flag the node that is referenced via an entity form submission with rules?

Tags: rules, flags, entities

I am trying to recreate an "enquiry basket". I am using [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform), [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/Views) and [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/Flag).

I have a node content type called Custom product. I am referencing different entity forms from each product node. As soon as the entity form is submitted I want to flag the referenced node, with its form entity form values, thus creating an basket that can be submitted as a whole, grouped by date.

My problem comes in when creating the rule.

I have a rule :

> **Event** : After saving a new entity form submission.

My problem is that I can't seem to get to the referenced node and "flag" it.

How does one get to the referenced node from a entity form and flag it via rules?